# Nesting tab and stack navigation in React Native causes one of the screens to rerender every time a state hook is updated

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm developing a project with React Native and I've been stuck for a while now.

One of the project screens ("ListArray") contains a list of items which can be pressed and saved to a Context state array.

Each item on the list takes up the whole screen, and the problem is that when an item is pressed, the screen rerenders, returning to item number 1.

The logic works as intended: the items are saved (or deleted on pressing an item that is already saved) correctly, but I need to find a way to stop the screen from rerendering, or at least remain on the current item when it rerenders.

Here's the bare minimum code to reproduce the issue:

CONTEXT.JS

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react'

 const AppContext = createContext()

 const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  
  return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{array, setArray}}>
        {children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }

  export {AppContext, AppProvider}
```

APP.JS

```
import { AppProvider,} from './Context.js';
import ListArray from './ListArray.js'
import Settings from './Settings.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';            
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from './Home.js';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './Context.js';


const App = () => {

  const {setArray} = useContext(AppContext;

  useEffect(()=>{
    setArray([])
     },[]);

  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  function HomeScreenStack(){
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )}

    function ListArrayScreenStack(){
      return(
        <Stack.Navigator>
           <Stack.Screen name="ListArrayScreen" component={ListArray} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
     )}


  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    
  return(
   
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
              <Tab.Screen name="HomeScreenStack" component={HomeScreenStack} />
              <Tab.Screen name="ListArrayScreenStack"  component={ListArrayScreenStack} />
              <Tab.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={Settings} />
        </Tab.Navigator> 
     </NavigationContainer>
        )
  }


  export default function AppWrapper() {
    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <App />
      </AppProvider>
    );
  }
```

LISTARRAY.JS

```
import { FlatList, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import ListArrayItem from './ListArrayItem'
import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel";

const ListArray = () => {

    const data = [{id:'1', name:'Array item 1'}, {id:'2', name:'Array item 2'}, {id:'3', name:'Array item 3'}, {id:'4', name:'Array item 4'},{id:'5', name:'Array item 5'}]

    const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

    const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

    const CarouselCardItem = ( { item, index } ) => {
 
        return (
            <ListArrayItem id={item.id} name={item.name} deviceHeight={deviceHeight} deviceWidth={deviceWidth}/>
        ) 
      }
     
          return(
          
         <View>
       
            <Carousel
              layout="default"
              data={data}
              renderItem={CarouselCardItem}
              sliderHeight={deviceHeight}
              itemHeight={deviceHeight}
              inactiveSlideShift={0}
              decelerationRate={0.2}
              lockScrollWhileSnapping={true}
              vertical

            />

         </View>
           
        );}

export default ListArray;
```

LISTARRAYITEM.JS

```
import {View, Text, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import { useState,useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './Context.js';

const ListArrayItem = ({id, name, deviceHeight, deviceWidth}) => {

    const {array, setArray} = useContext(AppContext);

    const [isSaved, setIsSaved] = useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{

        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

            if(array[i].id === id){

                setIsSaved(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    },[])

    const PressHandler = () => {

       if(isSaved){
          
        setArray(array.filter(arrayItem => arrayItem.id !== id))
        setIsSaved(false);
       }
       else{

        setArray([...array, {id: id, name: name}]);
        setIsSaved(true);

       }
    }

    return(
        <View style={{height:deviceHeight, width:deviceWidth, flex:1, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'black'}}>
           <Pressable style={{width:deviceWidth, alignItems:'center', height:200, backgroundColor:'yellow'}} onPress={PressHandler}><Text>{name}</Text></Pressable>
           {isSaved && <Text>SAVED</Text>}
        </View>

    )
}

export default ListArrayItem;
```

SETTINGS.JS

```
import { View,FlatList,Text } from "react-native";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./Context";

const Settings = () => {

    const {array} = useContext(AppContext)

    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            data={array}
            renderItem={({item})=>{return(
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            )}}
            />
          
        </View>
    )
}

export default Settings;
```

At first I thought the problem had to do exclusively with Context API, causing a rerender every time "setArray" is called in ListArrayItem.js.

I also thought it could be the Snap Carousel library, but replacing it with a FlatList causes the exact same issue.

Then I tried to remove stack navigation (which is not an option in the actual application, here I just listed the incriminated screens to reproduce the problem) and I saw how it didn't go back to item number 1 on rerender, staying on the current item.

How could I make sure either ListArray screen doesn't rerender or at least it stays on the current item?